# How do I implement custom stream manipulators taking arguments?

Tags: c++, iomanip

For example, I want a stream manipulator that I can pass a `uint8_t` (`unsigned char`) to and have it output (for example):

`00` or `0f` or `a6`.

I know it's possible to have stream manipulators without arguments:

```
std::ostream &hex_format(std::ostream &out)
{
    out << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2);
    return out;
}

uint8_t x {15};
std::cout << hex_format << static_cast<int>(x); // should produce "0f"
```

but how can I create a manipulator that accepts arguments? Something like:

```
std::ostream &hex_format(std::ostream &out, uint8_t x)
{
    out << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2)
        << static_cast<int>(x);
    return out;
}

uint8_t x {15};
std::cout << hex_format(x); // (want to) produce "0f"
```

Comment: Make it a class with a constructor taking and storing your arguments; plus overloaded `operator<<` making use of them. You can look at how `std::setfill` and `std::setw` are implemented - they are manipulators taking arguments.

Comment: [Really useful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/custom-manipulators-with-arguments?view=vs-2019).

Comment: [Also useful](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/1769).

Answer (score 0):

Use a manipulator class:

```
struct hex_format {
    std::uint8_t number;

    hex_format(std::uint8_t x)
        :number{x}
    {
    }
};
```

Then define the appropriate operator:

```
template <typename CharT, typename Traits>
decltype(auto) operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, hex_format rhs)
{
    return os << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(x);
}
```

---

Off-topic: in fact, this will globally modify the state of the stream and affect later stream operations.  You can fix this by saving the state:

```
template <typename CharT, typename Traits>
decltype(auto) operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, hex_format rhs)
{
    auto flags = os.flags();
    os << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(x);
    os.flags(flags);
    return os;
}
```